# Header information in kafka producer API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a json payload which i want to send as header in producer Api

```
{
    "type": "record_created",
    "version": 1,
    "orgId": "",
    "userId": "",
    "userName": "",
    "correlationId": "",
    "jobId": ""
}
```

Above payload should be sent as header

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Integer, String>(topic, messageNo, records,header)
```

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways

1)
getHeaders and add Header

```
ProducerRecord<Integer, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Integer, String>("topic", 1, "message");
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("type", "record_created".getBytes()));
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("type", "record_created".getBytes()));    
producer.send(record);
```

2)
use ProducerRecord(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V value,  Iterable headers)

but this way you have to decide the partition-no

Comment: You don't have to decide the partition in case of 2) - you can pass in `null`.