# Kafka - Adding custom headers to record metadata

Tags: apache-kafka

Does kafka allow adding custom headers to record metadata. Code suggests that it doesn't. Has anyone tried it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Custom Headers in Kafka Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025627/adding-custom-headers-in-kafka-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [the Java API](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord-java.lang.String-java.lang.Integer-java.lang.Long-K-V-java.lang.Iterable-) has headers

```
public ProducerRecord(java.lang.String topic,
                          java.lang.Integer partition,
                          java.lang.Long timestamp,
                          K key,
                          V value,
                          java.lang.Iterable headers)
```

Creates a record with a specified timestamp to be sent to a specified topic and partition

```
Parameters:
    topic - The topic the record will be appended to
    partition - The partition to which the record should be sent
    timestamp - The timestamp of the record, in milliseconds since epoch. If null, the producer will assign the timestamp using System.currentTimeMillis().
    key - The key that will be included in the record
    value - The record contents
    headers - the headers that will be included in the record
```

Answer (score 3):

[apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) has included supporting for custom headers since 0.11.0.0 version through [**KIP-82** - Add Record Headers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82%2B-%2BAdd%2BRecord%2BHeaders).

For example, you can use this [method](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord-java.lang.String-java.lang.Integer-K-V-java.lang.Iterable-):

```java
public ProducerRecord(String topic,
                      Integer partition,
                      K key,
                      V value,
                      Iterable<Header> headers)
```

See also related questions:

1. [Adding Custom Headers in Kafka Message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44255759/7109598)
2. [Header information in kafka producer API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147117/7109598)